# what relationship in class diagram is appropriate?

Tags: class-diagram

There are class A and class B.
A use B as member data's type.

[image]

What is a right relationship between A and B in class diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that seems like a dependency relationship, A depends on B.

A ----> B